# str_ireplace() - can i get the string to be replaced?

Tags: php

I have the following strings.

```
$string = "Welcome to Lorien.";
$search = "welcome";
```

Now I want to search for `$search` in `$string` and ignoring the case, so:

```
$result = str_ireplace($search,  '<b>'.$search.'</b>' ,$string);
```

`$result` should look like this: **welcome** to Lorien.

Is there a way i can use the case of `$string` so it looks like this: **Welcome** to Lorien.

Like getting the part of the string which is getting replaced and use it?

Comment: your expected output is exactly same to the input you provided. So i am confused what you are trying to do?

Comment: Use `preg_replace` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [preg_replace()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) for this:

```
$string = "Welcome to Lorien.";
$search = "welcome";

$result = preg_replace("/{$search}/i", '<b>$0</b>', $string);
```

- The `/i`-flag makes the matching case-insensitive.
- The `$0` will be replaced with the matched string from the original string so the casing will always be correct.

Demo: https://3v4l.org/vN9Km

Answer (score 0):

Op wants to find the string with a given pattern, as case insensitive, and uppercase and bold if I got correctly.

If that's the case, here's what needs to be done.

```
<?php

$string = "Welcome to Lorien.";
$search = "welcome";

echo str_ireplace($search, '<b>'.ucwords($search).'</b>', $string);
// Outputs: <b>Welcome</b> to Lorien.
```

Example: https://3v4l.org/Gmsqp